# ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I'm making a form in Oracle Apex.
I'm trying to make select list based on answer in previous question with following code

> SELECT to_char (data, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), id FROM seanse WHERE id_film=:P15_TYTUL;

When I'm trying to submit form, I get following error

> ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

although the day of the month is between 1 and last day of month (ex. 09/06/2020 21:20). I've tried changing format of the date, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Is Apex treating the returned string as a string, or as a date? If the latter it might be converting it implicitly and it's tripping over the format at that point. Presumably `data` is actually a date - not a string?

Comment: do you have a column "data" in your table "seanse" ? That is a very unusual name, could that be a typo ? If so, typo in the question or typo in your code. What is the data type of that column ?

Answer (score 0):

Searching a bit of this ORA ERROR, I've found information about this error and it says that:

The Oracle docs note this on the ORA-01847 error:

```
   ORA-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
```

Cause: The day of the month listed in a date is invalid for the specified month. The day of the month (DD) must be between 1 and the number of days in that month.

**Action: Enter a valid day value for the specified month.**

[http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01847_day_of_month_must_be_between_1_and_last_day_of_month.htm#:~:text=The%20Oracle%20docs%20note%20this,invalid%20for%20the%20specified%20month.http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01847_day_of_month_must_be_between_1_and_last_day_of_month.htm#:~:text=The%20Oracle%20docs%20note%20this,invalid%20for%20the%20specified%20month](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01847_day_of_month_must_be_between_1_and_last_day_of_month.htm#:%7E:text=The%20Oracle%20docs%20note%20this,invalid%20for%20the%20specified%20month.http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01847_day_of_month_must_be_between_1_and_last_day_of_month.htm#:%7E:text=The%20Oracle%20docs%20note%20this,invalid%20for%20the%20specified%20month).

But also I have doubts about how to change this.

Can you try to change the format mask in APEX?

[image]